# ToBase64String,C# 3.5

Tags: c#-3.0, zip

While converting a **zip** file to base64 encoded string,Which is needed to sent mail with MIME support I use

```
var encodedContent = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(File.ReadAllText(zipFilePath)));
```

However all the attachements I receive is corrupted.It seems base64 encoding is not correct. Can anyone advise on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.ReadAllText` is designed to read *text*, and therefore applies encodings (and [that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368%28VS.90%29.aspx) overload applies heuristics to determine the encoding). This is why you're then needing to "un-encode" to get bytes.

Applying different encodings in that way is likely to lead to changes in the byte stream (that's the point of encodings).

Better to read bytes directly out of the file, with something like [`File.ReadAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes%28VS.90%29.aspx) which can be passed directly to [`ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string%28VS.90%29.aspx).